# Magento 2 - How to uninstall module?

Tags: magento2, module, uninstall

How to uninstall module ?

I read this  [document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html#instgde-cli-uninst-mod-uninst)

But it was not successful, and display below:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall SP_Gridthumbs
```

> SP_Gridthumbs is not an installed composer package

Comment: Details Description of uninstall module, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/uninstall-module-with-database-table-schema-magento-2/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

it says in the documentation you linked, this:

> This command works only with modules defined as Composer packages.

If you did not install the module via composer, it won't work.
You can only disable it via `bin/magento module:disable SP_Gridthumbs`.

To remove the module, remove the folder `SP/Gridthumbs`, remove the record with module = 'SP_Gridthumbs' from the table `setup_module` and remove any other tables or records added by the install of the module.
Also remove the line with `SP_Gridthumbs` from `app/etc/config.php`

Comment: How to remove all this module out of project, your way just disable.

Comment: @MagentoOdoo.com see my update

Comment: You should also clean the cache

Comment: I tested it. `Remove the line with SP_Gridthumbs from app/etc/config.php` doesn't need. Magento will auto remove the record by run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: Actually I have to update one record from table and this code put in InstallData.php::install()  and when enable module and setup:upgrade it run my code. 

and now i need when i disable the module then should also remove recorde from table i did code in Uninstall::uninstall but not trigger when disable module.

Which file trigger when disable the module and setup:upgrade

Comment: I also had to use this to regenerate composer autoload files: composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 13):

Below are the steps to Uninstall Module Manually for Magento 2

- Delete the Module folder from `{folder path}\app\code`
- Remove module entry from `setup_module`
- Run command

  > {magento project root path}>{php path}\php.exe bin/magento setup:upgrade                   => Setup Upgrade
  >
  > {magento project root path}>{php path}\php.exe bin/magento cache:flush                     => Clear Cache

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content
composer remove VendorName/VendorExtensionRepository
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

For composer modules:

```
php bin/magento module:disable <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> --clear-static-content
php bin/magento module:uninstall <ExtensionProvider_ExtensionName> -r
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Running setup: upgrade while there are modules that were not installed via composer will get them being installed and enabled again which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid see updated answer

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to uninstall a composer installed module**

- bin/magento module:disable Namespace_ModuleName
- bin/magento module:uninstall Namespace_ModuleName
- composer remove namespace/module-name
- bin/magento cache:flush

**Steps to uninstall a manually added module in app/code**

- bin/magento module:disable Namespace_ModuleName
- remove directory from app/code manually
- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 2):

HERE IS THE STEP BY STEP GUIDE TO UNINSTALL ANY THIRD PARTY MODULE FROM MAGENTO 2 MANUALLY.

```
Step 1: Remove the module Vendor_Mymodule from app\etc\config.php

Step 2: Drop module tables or columns from database, please check app\code\Vendor\Module\Setup folder for more information

Step 3: Remove the folder app\code\vendor\Mymodule

Step 4: Remove module configuration settings from core_config_data table by running the following query


 DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module LIKE 'vendor_Mymodule';
Step 5: Run the following command by logging onto your SSH server

 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
But if you have installed the module via composer then you can run the following list of commands by SSHing on the box to uninstall third party module

 php bin/magento module:uninstall -r {{module_name}}
for example

php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Scommerce_GoogleTagManagerPro
-r flag removes module data 

Run the following command once module has been successfully uninstalled.

 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

To Custom Magento2 Module

```
step1: disable the module 
$php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_MyModule
step2: remove the folder from directory app/code/Vendor
step3: remove the line of code from app/etc/config.php file.
```

for more on uninstalling 3rd party/composer installed extensions

> https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento2-uninstall-module.html

Comment: What if you've got different modules by the same vendor you want to keep? Your SQL queries will break these.

Comment: Just edited my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall a custom module and NOT an extension from the marketplace do this:

1. Run command: `$ bin/magento module:disable <module_name>`
2. Remove directory and sub-directory of your custom module: `app/code/<module_name>`
3. Remove record in database table referencing your custom module: `setup_module`
4. Run command: `$ bin/magento setup:upgrade`
5. Verify that `<module_name>` entry from `app/etc/config.php` is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2: How to uninstall module

**1. If you installed it manually:**

```
remove the folder app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>
drop module tables from database
remove the config settings.

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'   
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'

remove the module <Vendor>_<Module> from app/etc/config.php

remove the module <Vendor>_<Module> from table setup_module

DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='<Vendor>_<Module>'    
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='<Vendor>_<Module>'
```

**2.If you installed it via composer:**

```
run this in console
php bin/magento module:status
php bin/magento module:disable mirasvit/module-core --clear-static-content
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>    
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento c:f
composer remove mirasvit/module-core
```

Hope Someone get help

Comment: I just created module without using composer.json file after the day i installed composer.json is it possible to uninstalled the module using composer? my module => https://github.com/ZusZus/simple-module/tree/master/app/code/Gta/Mymod @matinict

Comment: @zus to avoid conflict first you need to remove code from app/code , yes i think   u can install/uninstall via composer, (ur module link  may be not work composer install u need to add your repo https://packagist.org )

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wise to first disable the module using

> php bin/magento module:disable **modulename**

because this checks for dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall extension from magento 2:

1. Go to your magento project directory in CLI and check for module status, by running command
       `php bin/magento module:status`
2. If it is enable make it disable by running command
      `php bin/magento module:disable <extension name>`
3. Go to database and search for 'setup_module' table and search for your extension name and delete it
4. Delete the your extension name folder from app/code folder
5. Run the setup:upgrade command.
6. You have succesfulley uninstalled the extension.

Answer (score 0):

`php bin/magento module:disable Amasty_Checkout`

https://prnt.sc/wacrl8

verify composer cli from composer.json file of magento root directory

`composer remove amasty/module-single-step-checkout`

`php-cli bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score -7):

1. Open `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleUninstallCommand.php`

and replace

```
protected function validate(array $modules)
{
    $messages = [];
    $unknownPackages = [];
    $unknownModules = [];
    $installedPackages = $this->composer->getRootRequiredPackages();
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        if (array_search($this->packageInfo->getPackageName($module), $installedPackages) === false) {
            $unknownPackages[] = $module;
        }
        if (!$this->fullModuleList->has($module)) {
            $unknownModules[] = $module;
        }
    }
    $unknownPackages = array_diff($unknownPackages, $unknownModules);
    if (!empty($unknownPackages)) {
        $text = count($unknownPackages) > 1 ?
            ' are not installed composer packages' : ' is not an installed composer package';
        $messages[] = '<error>' . implode(', ', $unknownPackages) . $text . '</error>';
    }
    if (!empty($unknownModules)) {
        $messages[] = '<error>Unknown module(s): ' . implode(', ', $unknownModules) . '</error>';
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

with

```
protected function validate(array $modules)
{
    $messages = [];
    $unknownPackages = [];
    $unknownModules = [];
    $installedPackages = $this->composer->getRootRequiredPackages();
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        if (array_search($this->packageInfo->getPackageName($module), $installedPackages) === false) {
            $unknownPackages[] = $module;
        }
        if (!$this->fullModuleList->has($module)) {
            $unknownModules[] = $module;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($unknownModules)) {
        $messages[] = '<error>Unknown module(s): ' . implode(', ', $unknownModules) . '</error>';
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

2. Open `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ModuleUninstaller.php`

and replace

```
public function uninstallCode(OutputInterface $output, array $modules)
{
    $output->writeln('<info>Removing code from Magento codebase:</info>');
    $packages = [];
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo $packageInfo */
    $packageInfo = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfoFactory')->create();
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $packages[] = $packageInfo->getPackageName($module);
    }
    $this->remove->remove($packages);
}
```

with

```
public function uninstallCode(OutputInterface $output, array $modules)
{
    $output->writeln('<info>Removing code from Magento codebase:</info>');
    $packages = [];
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo $packageInfo */
    $packageInfo = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfoFactory')->create();
    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $packages[] = $packageInfo->getPackageName($module);
    }
}
```

3. Say "lyaska masyaska"

Note, the solution isn't recommended on production server