# Can't remove extensions

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, fatal-error, uninstall

**Preconditions**

- Magento 2.1.5
- PHP 7.0.16
- MySQL 5.7.16

**Steps to reproduce**

Extension installed via composer

```
$ php bin/magento module:uninstall Mageplaza_Seo -c -> Fail by authentication

$ ln -s /home/user/.composer/auth.json var/composer_home

$ php bin/magento module:uninstall Mageplaza_Seo -c
```

Successful

**Expected result**

Uninstall extension

**Actual result**

```
1. Broken site report
a:4:{i:0;s:217:"Cannot read contents from file "/var/www/html/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-seo-extension/etc/module.xml" Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-seo-extension/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory";i:1;s:4849:"#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php(120): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->fileGetContents('/var/www/html/v...')
....
```

I remove references in eav table, try and nothing, I had to install it again

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>
```

> This command works only with modules defined as Composer packages.

If you did not install the module via composer, it won't work.
You can only disable it via bin/magento module:disable _.

To remove the module, remove the folder *, remove the record with module = '*' from the table setup_module and remove any other tables or records added by the install of the module.
Also remove the line with _ from app/etc/config.php

Ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105196/35758