# How to uninstall Stripe module installed in app/code

Tags: magento2, module, vendor, stripe, app

One of our client stores has had Stripe module installed in app/code as shown in the image below.

[image]

I need to uninstall it and reinstall its latest version in vendor folder. Could you please share steps/links to Magento devdoc that explains how to uninstall a module installed in app?

Answer (score 0):

Check this for how to uninstall module in `app/code` and etc...

**[Magento 2 - How to uninstall module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105193/magento-2-how-to-uninstall-module)**

After you uninstall module you can delete your module using manually or using command. After that you can run basic commands.

---

Check this link for how to install module using composer.

**https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/adobe-commerce/install**

*`THANKS`*

Answer (score 0):

You are use the MagePlaza Extension,So you need to check this one.

https://www.mageplaza.com/install-magento-2-extension/